# How to send Garbage Collect array to windows form

Tags: windows, forms, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I am having an issue with the windows form. I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong, I assume it is a syntax problem. What I am trying to do is make an array of customers and pass that array to the form so I can work with the data inside the header file for the form. My problem is, my compiler complains when I try to pass the array to it. Here is a small piece of the code I am working on:

```
#include "Form1.h"
#include "customer.h"
#include "Bank.h"
#include <array>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace CppGUI_Project;



int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) {
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

bank^ bank1 = gcnew bank();
bank^ bank2 = gcnew bank();
bank^ bank3 = gcnew bank();
bank^ bank4 = gcnew bank();
bank^ bank5 = gcnew bank();

customer^ john = gcnew customer(101, 1234, bank1, 1000, 2000);
customer^ jeff = gcnew customer(102, 1234, bank2, 2000, 4000);
customer^ jane = gcnew customer(103, 1234, bank3, 3000, 8000);
customer^ jimmy = gcnew customer(104, 1234, bank4, 4000, 8000);
customer^ Jasmine = gcnew customer(105, 1234, bank5, 5000, 16000);

array<customer^>^ custArray = gcnew array<customer^>(5);
custArray[0] = john;

Form1^ aForm = gcnew Form1(custArray); // Problem here, won't accept it.

Application::Run(aForm);
return 0;
}
```

I have tried using different data structures and other things, but I am not sure what the next right place / step is.

Thanks

Comment: The most obvious mistake is that you forgot to add the constructor that takes an array argument.  We can't see it.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I am an idiot. I forgot to update the overloaded constructor to the form. Opps.